# Kotlin Companion Object Limitation about Reflection and Inheritance

Tags: inheritance, kotlin, reflection, kotlin-companion

**Assume:**

- I need a lot of companion (static-like) methods for subclasses of `Parent`
- I need a lot of method (non-static) for subclasses of `Parent`
- I have more than 50 subclasses of `Parent`
- `clazz` and some other fields must compute per class (not instance) due to performance
- Expect that Companion methods and non-Companion methods use computed members (ex: `clazz`)
- **Last but not least** `Parent` and `MyCompanion` can have complicated logic but subclasses of `Parent` like `Child` should be in the simplest form as possible

**Question:**

how to retrieve correct class name of `Child` in both below expressions:

```
Child().printClass()
Child.printClassUsingCompanion()
```

**Code: [TRY IT](https://pl.kotl.in/YGaOgjPNK)**

```
open class MyCompanion {
  var clazz = this::class.java.declaringClass.name
  // and many more members that will compute using reflection with complex logic
  fun printClassUsingCompanion() = println(clazz)
}

open class Parent {
  companion object : MyCompanion()
  fun printClass() = println(clazz)
}

class Child: Parent() {
  companion object : MyCompanion()
}

fun main() {
  Child().printClass()              //output: Parent
  Child.printClassUsingCompanion()  //output: Child
}
```